# How to display downto in For loops with Algorithmix package

Tags: algorithmicx

I want a `For` loop as

`For i \gets 20 downto 0 do`

I've looked at the [algorithmicx](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf) documentation, however, I couldn't see that.

- Is it possible to achieve this?
- Even further, can we achieve `downto 20 by 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define both `\Downto` and `\By` in a manner that is similar to all the other keywords within [`algpseudocode`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\algnewcommand{\Downto}{\textbf{ downto }}
\algnewcommand{\By}{\textbf{ by }}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \For{$i \gets 20 \Downto 0 \By 2$}
      \State Do something with $i$
    \EndFor
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see. This is an external solution that I was not expecting, and since they are \textbf no problem at all. Thanks.

Comment: @kelalaka: You can define a new `\For`, but my proposal seems equally flexibly, whether you want a **downto** with/without a **by** (say).

Comment: Yes, this is a simple hack to solve the issue and flexible without complications.